# Update this module to the last version

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm inside a folder

```
c:\nodeProject\node_modules\express>
```

Now, i want to update the module here, to the latest version.
I want NPM to check the package.json, and update this module.

What is the command line to do it?

Comment: If you going to downvote, because I didn't read this: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update. I read. This is not what I'm searching for. `npm update` update the dependencies. Not the module inside the current folder

Comment: This is exactly what you need. You just need to specify the package name (and version). `npm update pkgName --save`.

Comment: Note that `npm update` respects [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), so if you want to change to a different major version, you will need to either edit your `package.json` or uninstall and reinstall the package.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm uninstall express
npm install express@latest --save
```

That's what your looking for ?